# How do I set a static IP on my Virtual Server?

Tags: networking, ip, static-ip

Can anyone help me to set a static ip in my virtual linux server machine? I did everything but still I am not able to set a static ip.

I did the following changes in /etc/network/interface file.

## The primary network interface

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static

address 192.168.56.1
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.5.140
dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4
```

and saved the file. Then

```
 ifup eth0
```

but it is not working. 
Please help me to configure it.
Thanks

Comment: What does "it is not working" mean? Please give as much details as possible.

Comment: after setting static ip i am trying to access  my virtual machine through winscp or putty but it do not let me in virtual machine.

Comment: can any one help me to set static ip in my virtual linux server machine

i did every thing but still i am not able to set static ip.

host OS is windows 7 guest server is Linux 14.04

I am using oracle vm virtual box

Adapter 1 : is bridge adapter Adapter 2 : is bridge adapter

I did following changes in /etc/network/interface file.

The primary network interface

auto eth0 iface eth0 inet static

address 192.168.56.1 netmask 255.255.255.0 gateway 192.168.5.140 dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4

save this file

and then sudo ifup eth0 but it is not working. it gives error.

Comment: Please [edit](http://askubuntu.com/posts/525908/edit) your question and add above comment in your question.

Answer (score 1):

Edit the correct file `/etc/network/interfaces` ([Relevant man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/interfaces))

That last `s` is important, unless you simply had a typo when making this post.

Then simply restart networking: `sudo ifdown eth0 && sudo ifup eth0`

Comment: `service networking restart` [no longer does anything of use](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ifupdown/+bug/1301015). Use `sudo ifdown eth0 && sudo ifup eth0`.

Comment: Dang, good to know.. (Also, nice man-page link mate, cheers!)

Comment: Thanks Bro for your answer. issue resolved by changing the gateway, some how i used wrong gateway address.

Comment: Ahh, its clear now, I can see that too: 192.168.5.140 should be 192.168.56.140?

Comment: @sachin Please make an answer describing how you fixed your problem to help out future guests. Nice job debugging your own question!

Comment: Sure Brother. This interface file working fine for me # This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address 192.192.4.222
gateway 192.192.7.200
netmask 255.255.0.0
dns-nameservers 192.192.7.200